# Exposing external services in Mule API gateway

Tags: mule

I have a query on a design hope you guys can clarify my doubt.

I have a specific requirement in which **Mule** is used just to expose the back end services in **API gateway**, backend services are written in **Spring boot** and other technology, all these services needs to be exposed in API gateway.

> Is this a good practice to do that and if yes how can we do that?

I saw that in API manager we can create proxy layer on top of the services developed in Mule but is it possible to create proxies for the services developed in different technologies?

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely ... For creating proxy service, it doesn't matter what type of technology does the backend service have. 
It can create a proxy layer for any kind of backend service available either locally, in cloud or other remote location till the service url is accessible. 
This proxy will create an additional layer hiding the actual url to the external world.

Comment: what are the typical steps to proxy a spring boot service?

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't matter what technology you are using for development as long as those are REST services and accessible to the cloudhub application. You can deploy those on-premise and can integrate your local runtime with cloudhub. Also, mule supports spring projects and you can directly configure your spring project/details inside [mule](https://www.mulesoft.com/resources/esb/mule-esb-best-choice-spring-integration).